# Matrix transformation $f:\mathbb{R}^{3}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am self-learning Linear Algebra (mainly through Khan Academy and Youtube). I encountered this linear transformation, and was wondering how would this be solved.

$f:\mathbb{R}^{3}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3}$

$f \begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
y\\ 
z
\end{pmatrix} $  = $ \begin{pmatrix}
4 & 1 & 3\\ 
2 &-1 & 3\\ 
2 & 2 & 0
\end{pmatrix} $ $\begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
y\\ 
z
\end{pmatrix} $

Establish $x, y$ and $z$ such that,

$f\begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
y\\ 
z
\end{pmatrix} $ = $\begin{pmatrix}
4\\ 
5\\ 
-1
\end{pmatrix} $

Do I just need to multiply the values of $f$ for the $3\times3$ matrix? What does this mean overall?

Comment: Hint: this is a system of equations.

Comment: You wrote this question incorrectly and I think you should fix it to make things more clear for yourself. You write $f = (x, y, z)^t = A$ where $A$ is that matrix.  But of course, these cannot be actually equal. $f$ is a function, $(x, y, z)^t$ is a column vector, and $A$ is a matrix. Think through what you actually mean to define your function $f$ as.

Comment: In your first line of equation I suppose you have meant $$f\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\ldots$$ There shouldn't two equality signs...yet you repeated this once again. It's odd

Comment: @DonAntonio  You are right! I just checked. Thank you

Comment: @paulblartmathcop I see! I see that it's wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to solve the non-homogeneous system

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
4 & 1 & 3\\ 
2 &-1 & 3\\ 
2 & 2 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
y\\ 
z
\end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix}
4\\ 
5\\ 
-1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Form then the augmented coefficients matrix and reduce it by rows:

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
4 & 1 & 3&:&4\\ 
2 &-1 & 3&:&5\\ 
2 & 2 & 0&:&-1
\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_1\leftrightarrow R_3\cdot\left(\frac12\right)}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0&:&-1/2\\
2 &-1 & 3&:&5\\
4 & 1 & 3&:&4\\ 
 \end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_2-2R_1\\R_3-4R_1}\longrightarrow$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0&:&-1/2\\
0 &-3 & 3&:&6\\
0 & -3 & 3&:&6\\ 
 \end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_3-R_2}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0&:&-1/2\\
0 &-3 & 3&:&6\\
0 & 0 & 0&:&0\\ 
 \end{pmatrix}$$

Well, there are infinite solutions to the above system: begin with row $3$ , and remember the columns represent $\;x, y, z\;$ from left to right, so:

$$R_2:\;\;-3y+3z=6\implies y=z-2\\R_1:\;\;x+y=-\frac12\implies x=-\frac12-y=-\frac12-z+2=\frac32-z$$

Now just choose a nice $\;z\;$ , say $\;z=0\implies y=-2\,,\,\,x=\cfrac32\;$ , and one solution to your problem is

$$\begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
y\\ 
z
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
3/2\\ 
-2\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$$

as you can easily check.

Comment: I see! Wow, I understood. Perhaps the most complex thing for me is that it has infinite solutions. That's new for me. Thank you very much, I really understood. I will try to remember and research more about it!

Answer (score -2):

You are given that $\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}4 & 1 & 3 \\ 2 & -1 & 3 \\ 2 & 2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}$.

Of course, $\begin{pmatrix}4 & 1 & 3 \\ 2 & -1 & 3 \\ 2 & 2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}4x+ y+ 3z \\ 2x- y+ 3z \\ 2x+ 2y \end{pmatrix}$.

So we have $\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}4x+ y+ 3z \\ 2x- y+ 3z \\ 2x+ 2y \end{pmatrix}$.

That gives us three equations:
$$x= 4x+ y+ 3z\quad\text{which reduces to}\quad 3x+ y+ 3z= 0.$$
$$y= 2x- y+ 3z\quad\text{which reduces to}\quad 2x- 2y+ 3z= 0.$$
$$z= 2x+ 2y\quad\text{which reduces to}\quad 2x+ 2y- z= 0.$$

An obvious solution to that is $x= y= z= 0.$
Notice that the determinant is

$$\begin{align*}
\left|\begin{array}{ccc} 3 & 1 & 3 \\ 2 & -2 & 3 \\ 2 & 2 & -1 \end{array}\right|&= 3\left|\begin{array}{cc} -2 & 3 \\ 2 & -1\end{array}\right|- \left|\begin{array}{cc}2 & 3 \\ 2 & -1\end{array}\right|+ 3\left|\begin{array}{cc} 2 & -2 \\ 2 & 2 \end{array}\right|\\[5pt]
&= 3(2- 6)- (-2- 6)+ 3(4+ 4)\\[5pt]
&= -12+ 8+ 24\\[5pt]
&= 20\\[5pt]
\end{align*}$$

Since that is not $0, x= y= z= 0$  is the only solution.

Comment: OP is trying to solve $f(x, y, z) = (4, 5, -1)$ not $f(x, y, z)=(x, y, z)$.